# Do django Class Based Views, CreateView and UpdateView, clean the data behind the scenes?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I know the data is validated. But I can't figure out if the CBV clean the data. When using `class className(forms.Form):` OR class `className(forms.ModelForm)` you add (inside your CBV):

```
def post(self, request):
form = HomeForm()
    if form.is_valid():
        text = form.cleaned_data['p]
```

Can someone tell me if you have to also clean your data manually of if the CreateView and UpdateView clean the data behind the scenes?

Answer (score 1):

CreateView and Update view automatically clean the data based on the model fields, For example a field in a model

```
comments=models.CharField("Comments",max_length=200)
```

Will check that the input length is less than 200 and also that the field is not blank.
If model field is as below.

```
comments=models.CharField("Comments",max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)
```

Input is allowed to be blank. Similarly Email Field in a model as below

```
email=models.EmailField("Email Address",unique=True)
```

Will run checks to see if the Field is an email using the Email Validator.

If required the Model form views provide a form_valid() implementation that saves the model automatically. You can override this if you have any special requirements; see below for examples.

[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/][1]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Couldn't find a clear answer to this. Thanks

Comment: To be specific, those views automatically create modelrorms which are responsible for cleaning the data.